# ldap3/python3 Connection modify() function error(malformed change) with active directory

Tags: python-3.x, active-directory, ldap

i have an active directory running and would like to change an attribute of an user. Im using the python3 ldap3 library and the modify() method.
My code below trows an exception every time i try to modify the user.

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, MODIFY_REPLACE

server = Server('ldaps://domain.local:636', port = 636, use_ssl = True)
try:
    conn = Connection(server, user="philipp@domain.local", password="MYPW", auto_bind=True)
    print("User found")
except:
    print("User not found or connection error")


result = conn.modify('CN=phil stone,OU=Firewall,DC=domain,DC=local',{'rules': [(MODIFY_REPLACE, ['replaced-text'])]})

print(result)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/hgfs/shared/eclipse/osfipa/ldap/ldap_write.py", line 28, in <module>
    result = conn.modify('CN=phil stone,OU=Firewall,DC=domain,DC=local',{'rules': [(MODIFY_REPLACE, ['replaced-text'])]})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ldap3/core/connection.py", line 763, in modify
    raise LDAPChangesError(self.last_error)
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPChangesError: malformed change
```

In the AD GUI i have checked the Attribute "distinguishedName" of the User(Object) and its Value is "CN=philipp stone,OU=Firewall,DC=domain,DC=local".
So the DN for the modify function should be correct. And i want to change the "rules" attribute.

Any Ideas what im doing wrong here?
Thx in advance.

Comment: I don't know pyhton, but it looks strange to me that you try to modify an entry with a mod_replace without providing either the attribute you want to replace nor the value with which you want to replace with

Comment: Everything you have mentioned is there, the Attribute is 'rules' the value i want to replace it with is the string "replaced-text"

Comment: You know what, there is edit history on stackoverflow. And there was no `"replaced-text"` when I posted the comment. In addition, as not knowing a thing about python, but some about LDAP, a modify operation with an empty value provided should by the protocol RFC be interpreted as a modify delete, hence the stack trace imho : `[(MODIFY_DELETE, []])]` (which it was 30sec ago). So being taken for a fool, I wish you goog luck on this

Comment: i tested it with the replaced string, should have copied the whole code. But anyways, that wasnt even the problem. see the answer below. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3/issues/42

There is a simple syntax error.  In the above link one can finde the answer.
The simple solution was to change it like the code below.

```
result = conn.modify('CN=phil stone,OU=Firewall,DC=domain,DC=local',{'rules': (MODIFY_REPLACE, ['replaced-text'])})
```

Look at the part "MODIFY_REPLACE replaced-text", there is no list([]) around it;)